# Get min/max int in a list of tuples of (int, string) in PolyML

Tags: sml, ml, polyml

I have seen this question for Python, But I have the same question for SML (PolyMl).

I want to create a function to extract from a list of tuples `(int, string)` the string value of the tuple with minimum `int`.

For example, if I have this list:

```
l = [('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('d', 6)]
```

The output should be `'c'`, because the minimum integer is in the tuple `('c', 1)`. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

```
val l = [(#"a", 5), (#"b", 3), (#"c", 1), (#"d", 6)]

fun min [] = NONE
  | min [x] = SOME x
  | min ((c1,n1) :: (c2,n2) :: xs) = if n1 < n2 then
                                       min ((c1,n1) :: xs) 
                                     else
                                       min ((c2,n2) :: xs)

val SOME (c,_) = min l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val lst = [(#"a", 5), (#"b", 3), (#"c", 1), (#"d", 6)];

(* The first item of a tuple is fetched with #1. *)
#1(List.foldl
    (fn ((new as (_,n)), (old as (_,n0))) =>
      if n < n0 then new else old)
    (hd lst)
    (tl lst));

(* val it = #"c" : char *)
```